# Provide redirection to commands used in compound commands

Tags: bash

If I want to provide redirection for inputs or outputs (`< myfile`, or `> myfile`) for commands `test-commands`, `consequent-commands`, `command1`, and `command2` in

```
if test-commands; then
consequent-commands;

until test-commands; do consequent-commands; done

while test-commands; do consequent-commands; done

command1 && command2

command1 || command2
```

where shall I place the redirections?

For example, I saw

```
while read a; 
  do echo "$a"; 
done < myfile;
```

I wonder why put `< myfile` after `done`, instead of after `read a`?

That also makes me think more generally (as the beginning part of this post):

- where a direction shall be placed for a command appearing in a compound command?
- Does it matter whether the redirection is output or input?
- if I place the redirection at the end of the compound command, how can I know which component command in the compound command   the redirection applies to?

Thanks.

Comment: *I wonder why put < myfile after done, instead of after read?* Have you tried ? What happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put redirections at any position in a simple command (i.e. invoking an alias, function, builtin or executable with parameters). On the other hand, if you want to apply a redirection to compound commands, the redirections have to come afterwards. This is how the shell syntax is designed. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
<myinput mycommand argument
mycommand <myinput argument
mycommand argument <myinput
```

whereas the redirection can't be moved in

```
while …; do …; done <myinput
{ command1; command2; } <myinput
```

You can only apply a redirection to a compound command if it ends with a keyword or with punctuation. To apply redirection to something like `foo && bar` or `foo; bar` or `foo | bar`, put the command in braces, e.g.

```
{ foo && bar; } <myinput
```

---

The scripts

```
while read a; do
  echo "$a"
done <myfile
```

and

```
while read a <myfile; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

are both syntactically correct, but the second one doesn't do anything useful. A redirection operator on a command means:

1. Open the specified file.
2. Attach the specified file to the requisite file descriptor (e.g. 0 for `<`).
3. Run the command.
4. Close the file descriptor.

So `read a <myfile` opens the file again on each iteration, which means that it keeps reading the first line forever.

If you want to use a while-read loop and want to keep the surrounding standard input for the loop body, read from a different file descriptor.

```
while read a <&3; do
  # commands that can use stdin
done 3<myfile
```

The redirection operator `<&3` merely does file descriptor duplication, it doesn't “open the file again” — in the enumeration above, there's no step 1.

Comment: Thanks. Does the last example work the same with and without `<&3`? What does "keep the surrounding standard input for the loop body" mean?

Comment: From what references can I find "if you want to apply a redirection to compound commands, the redirections have to come afterwards." and "You can only apply a redirection to a compound command if it ends with a keyword or with punctuation." ? In POSIX shell grammar, I found something similar to the first, but not the second.

Answer (score 1):

For simple commands, redirection positioning is flexible as long as it's on the same line and before any `;`. These are all valid:

```
command1 arg <file
<file command1 arg
command1 <file arg
```

You'll find the first form is generally preferred, stylistically speaking.

For commands connected by pipe or condition the redirection clearly should be on the same side as the associated command. If the first command must receive the input then you want:

```
command1 <file || command2
```

For command2 to receive the input:

```
command1 || command2 <file
```

In the case of `while`, `for` and other block-compound commands the necessity of putting redirection at the end is just a syntactical reality.

```
<file { command1 || command2; } # error
{ command1 || command2; } <file  # okay
```

A compound command acts as a single command in this context and so redirected input can't target command2 and exclude command1, for example.

Of course pipes are also sometimes an option so the second example above is similar to:

```
cat file | { command1 || command2; }
```

And in the case of your while loop:

```
cat myfile | while read a; do ...
```

I've used input in all these examples but the same applies to output. Where you need to pay attention is if you use both input and output or other multiple redirection configurations. Redirections are processed left to right.

Here is some more reading:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: In `{ cmd1 || cmd2; } < file`, `file` will be the stdin of both `cmd1` and `cmd2` (assuming `cmd2` is run, that is, that `cmd1` exits with a non-zero exit status). If `cmd1` consumes all the input and nothing has been added to `file` by the time `cmd2` starts reading its stdin, then `cmd2` will only see the end of the file (as it shares the same open file description (so cursor within the file) as `cmd1` had), but in `{ false || wc -c; } < file` for instance (where `false` reads nothing), `wc` will read the full content of the file.

Comment: Let me simplify. What I'm trying to convey is you can't "target" command2 as you could in the previous example.

Comment: No adjacent, just before a command terminator (usually newline or `;`). This is completely valid: `echo a long list of arguments in this command >file`