# Checking if a command fails - After redirects or before?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exit-status

We have an SQL script that we execute while redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to two separate files. Due to recent problems with the SQL script, we want to exit the script with an error in the event the SQL script causes an error to be returned.

Currently it reads:

```
executeHiveSql insertEvent.sql --hivevar Date=${DATEYMD} > logs/inesrtEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".log 2>logs/insertEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".err
```

In order to handle the failure of this SQL query I want to add a conditional check. Do I put that before the redirects or after? I.E.

```
executeHiveSql insertEvent.sql --hivevar Date=${DATEYMD} > logs/inesrtEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".log 2>logs/insertEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".err || { echo 'Process FAILED! Please check the logs.' ; log $AUTO_JOB_NAME "Failure" 1 "Archive process FAILED..."; exit 1; }
```

or

```
executeHiveSql insertEvent.sql --hivevar Date=${DATEYMD} || { echo 'Process FAILED! Please check the logs.' ; log $AUTO_JOB_NAME "Failure" 1 "Archive process FAILED..."; exit 1; } > logs/inesrtEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".log 2>logs/insertEvent"${DATEYYYYMMDD}".err
```

Comment: There's some discussion here about placement of redirects in compound commands that may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379863/provide-redirection-to-commands-used-in-compound-commands

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question about the order, but if the construct that you're using is hard to understand, then I suggest that you instead use a simpler construct.  There are no prizes for making everything a one liner :)

```
if ! executeHiveSql ... > ... 2> ...; then
    echo "Process FAILED!..."
    log ...
    exit 1
fi
```